# An error occurs when accessing the database

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

wondering why I am getting this error. 
Peeking in at the data it appears to be formatted correctly although when I run it I get a key error.
Here is a code snippet on how I am loading the data:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfRHD.png)

```
#%%input_data.py

def get_images(data_dir,label_dir):
img_width=random.randint(170,241)
img_height=img_width
with tf.name_scope('input'):  
    label=pd.read_csv(label_dir)
    index1=label['GalaxyID']

    label_list=label['Class']
    label_list=list(label_list)
    image_list=[]
```

&

```
#%% training.py
def train():

train_dir='GalaxyNet/data3/trainset/'
train_label_dir='GalaxyNet/data3/train_label.csv'
test_dir='GalaxyNet/data3/testset/'
test_label_dir='data3/test_label.csv' 

tra_image_batch, tra_label_batch = input_data.read_galaxy11(data_dir=train_dir,
                                                            label_dir=train_label_dir,
                                                            batch_size= BATCH_SIZE)
val_image_batch, val_label_batch = input_data.read_galaxy11_test(data_dir=test_dir,
                                                                 label_dir=test_label_dir,
                                                                 batch_size= BATCH_SIZE)
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Desktop\GalaxyNet\training.py", line 101, in <module>
train()
File "C:\Users\Desktop\GalaxyNet\training.py", line 32, in train
batch_size= BATCH_SIZE)
File "C:\Users\Desktop\GalaxyNet\input_data.py", line 116, in read_galaxy11
image,label=get_images(data_dir,label_dir)
File "C:\Users\Desktop\GalaxyNet\input_data.py", line 20, in get_images
label_list=label['Class']
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2995, in __getitem__
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Class'
```

Comment: There is no column named ```Class``` in the data you linked to. There are many columns with names in the format ```classn.m``` and ```Classn.m```

Comment: How to create a class column ??